# Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^4+2\cos(2\theta)x^2+1}$, determine the poles of $f(z)$ and come up with a proper contour.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^4+2\cos(2\theta)x^2+1}$, determine the poles of $f(z)$ and come up with a proper contour.

Good afternoon, I am quite new here and I hope this question is well received, assuming it hasn't been asked yet.

I have determined the poles of this function to be $ie^{i\theta}$, $ie^{-i\theta}$, $-ie^{i\theta}$, $-ie^{-i\theta}$, by using the quadratic formula $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$Where $z^4$ = $Z^2$, and $z^2 = Z$, after extending the real function to the complex plane.

My question is how do I find a proper contour for this function and what exactly do these poles imply when $\theta$ increases?

For example, if I consider $ie^{i\theta}$ to equal $-\sin\theta + i\cos\theta$, the imaginary portion is now $\cos\theta$ as opposed to the usual imaginary part being $\sin\theta$ for $e^{i\theta}$

It is safe to assume that $0<\theta<\pi$

I appreciate the help.